# Printout specific keys and values in nested .json data recursively in python

Tags: python, json, recursion, nested

So I have been going back and forth while trying to get specific values and keys out of a complex nested .json file.

I found out that a good approach is to use a recursive function.

I understand it on basic levels ect. but I cant manage to create one for my original file.

```
import json

#open json file in folder
with open('demk-bkp-001.json') as file:
data = json.load(file)
```

Here is the FULL .json data for reference: https://pastebin.com/hmjv81nS

My goal is to get every value in "name", "size" and "mountpoint".

Tips and examples dont seem to help me on multiple platforms hence I cant find a similar nested json file. please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Iterative approach: storing items to be processed in a data structure

A recursive function is one possibility; another possibility is to keep a data structure holding all the dictionaries you've encountered so far but haven't yet processed; then, as long as you still have at least one unprocessed dictionary, process it; if it has children, add them to the structure.
Here I use a simple python list:

```py
names, sizes, mountpoints = [],[],[]
to_be_processed = data['blockdevices']
while to_be_processed:
  d = to_be_processed.pop()
  names.append(d['name'])
  sizes.append(d['size'])
  mountpoints.append(d['mountpoint'])
  if 'children' in d:
    to_be_processed.extend(d['children'])
```

## Preserving order: using a FIFO instead of a LIFO data structure

Note that the iterative code provided above uses a python list with its methods `.extend()` and `.pop()`. Effectively, this uses the python list as a LIFO, a Last-In-First-Out data structure. If you want to preserve the order of your data, you want to use a FIFO, a First-In-First-Out data structure, instead. You could replace `.pop()` with `.pop(0)` to remove the first element instead of the last, but note that `list.pop(0)` is not an efficient operation in python; it requires copying all elements from the list. Instead, we can use a `collections.deque` object, with its `.extend()` and `.popleft()` methods:

- [documentation on `collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

```py
import collections

names, sizes, mountpoints = [],[],[]
to_be_processed = collections.deque(data['blockdevices'])
while to_be_processed:
  d = to_be_processed.popleft()
  names.append(d['name'])
  sizes.append(d['size'])
  mountpoints.append(d['mountpoint'])
  if 'children' in d:
    to_be_processed.extend(d['children'])
```

## Recursive approach

A recursive approach is possible too. Call it on  `data['blockdevices']`, and have it make a recursive call on the children if there are any.

```py
def process_data(d_list, names, sizes, mountpoints):
  for d in d_list:
    names.append(d['name'])
    sizes.append(d['size'])
    mountpoints.append(d['mountpoint'])
    if 'children' in d:
      process_data(d['children'], names, sizes, mountpoints)
  return names, sizes, mountpoints

process_data(data['blockdevices'], [], [], [])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It appears to be a missunderstanding from my side in which I forgot on how to recall the function properly! Is it ok if I ask here more stuff when I am in trouble once again?

Comment: @zed That depends what kind of trouble :)

Comment: Currently working on how to get a "name" under a condition. I want to find out the "name" which has their "size" set to >5.0T while not having another nested "children". In this example it would be "name": "sde" hence it is larger than 5.0T and does not have another "children" under "children".

Comment: hey once again! I tried to implement the first function (the non recursive one) which you have showed me, into a pandas dataframe that prints out multiple .json files but the order of the keys are printed out weirdly. The recursive one seems to work properly but I am unable to implement it into my dataframe code. https://pastebin.com/CVbbgjya

Comment: @zed The "weird order" doesn't surprise me, and should be relatively easy to fix. Remember that I talked about using "a data structure"? The only requirements on that data structure are that it has a function to add elements to the structure, and a function to remove and read elements from the structure. I used a python list with methods `.pop` and `.extend`. If you read the doc for these methods you'll see that this is effectively using the list as a stack, ie, a Last-In-First-Out structure. To read the data without reversing the order, you need a queue, ie, a First-In-First-Out structure.

Comment: So for instance you can use class `queue.SimpleQueue` from module `queue`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#simplequeue-objects

Comment: "AttributeError"
module 'queue' has no attribute 'SimpleQueue' well..

Comment: @zed The documentation specifies that `SimpleQueue` appeared in version 3.7. This means that if you're using python3.6 or older, it won't exist. In that case you can use `queue.queue` instead of `queue.SimpleQueue`. But I recommend upgrading your python version anyway.

Comment: @zed If you want to keep using python lists instead of module `queue`, a quick-fix of your code is to replace `process_data.extend(d['children'])` with `process_data = d['children'][::-1] + process_data`, which reverses the order in which the children are appended to `process_data` (you might want to also replace `process_data = json_text['blockdevices']` with `process_data = json_text['blockdevices'][::-1]`). But this might be slightly less efficient than using proper queues.

Comment: Just found out that you can use d = process_data.pop(0).  Index 0 allows it to start at the begining. -1 (default when no Index is given) has the LIFO arrangement. Seems to fix it for now.

Comment: @zed yes, you can fix it that way too. But keep in mind that it is not as efficient as using a data structure designed for LIFO. You might not care if the list remains small, but `list.pop(0)` is much less efficient than `list.pop()`, because removing the first element from a python list actually requires rewriting the whole list, whereas removing the last element from a python list is immediate.

Comment: Actually, a better alternative might be `collections.deque` instead of `queue.SimpleQueue`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Comment: I've edited the answer to add the collections.deque solution

Comment: You are a great help to this I cant thank you enough but thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey I am back. I gotta question again. I am trying to set a condition into the recursive code. I am trying to tell the function that it has to ignore every key that has a second "children" (every children starting with "name": "md0" and so on, basically the third block in the hierarchy) and only print out the keys that do not have a second "children" in them. In this example it would be "name": "sde".

Comment: @zed So you want to replace `names.append(d['name'])` with `if not ('children' in d and len(d['children']) >= 2): names.append(d['name'])`?

Comment: Want to print out only the `names, sizes, mountpoints` when the condition that `"children"` does not exist under `{ ... "children":[ { "name": "sde1"  ... } ]` is met. In this case it would only print the `names, sizes, mountpoints` from "sde" and "sde1" because it meets the condition that is has no other `"children"`. (sorry but its hard to explain with writing). In the end it ignores every "sd*" and "sd*1,2,3, ect." that has another `"children"` in it.

Comment: @zed `if 'children' not in d: blabla.append(blabla) else: to_be_processed.extend(d['children'])` ?

Comment: am going with the recursive option

Comment: @zed `if 'children' not in d: blabla.append(blabla) else:
      process_data(d['children'], names, sizes, mountpoints)`

Comment: doesnt seem to work properly: https://pastebin.com/LSssdmxd

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, using a recursive generator:

```
keys = ("name", "size", "mountpoint")

def traverse(objs):
    for obj in objs:
        yield {k: obj[k] for k in keys}
        yield from traverse(obj.get("children", []))

list(traverse(data["blockdevices"]))
[{'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sda', 'size': '931,5G'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sda1', 'size': '18,6G'},
 {'mountpoint': '/', 'name': 'md0', 'size': '18,6G'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sda2', 'size': '1K'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sda5', 'size': '9,3G'},
 {'mountpoint': '[SWAP]', 'name': 'md1', 'size': '9,3G'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sda6', 'size': '18,6G'},
 {'mountpoint': '/home', 'name': 'md2', 'size': '18,6G'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sda7', 'size': '885G'},
 {'mountpoint': '/var', 'name': 'md3', 'size': '884,8G'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sdb', 'size': '931,5G'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sdb1', 'size': '18,6G'},
 {'mountpoint': '/', 'name': 'md0', 'size': '18,6G'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sdb2', 'size': '1K'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sdb5', 'size': '9,3G'},
 {'mountpoint': '[SWAP]', 'name': 'md1', 'size': '9,3G'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sdb6', 'size': '18,6G'},
 {'mountpoint': '/home', 'name': 'md2', 'size': '18,6G'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sdb7', 'size': '885G'},
 {'mountpoint': '/var', 'name': 'md3', 'size': '884,8G'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sdc', 'size': '5,5T'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sdc1', 'size': '5,5T'},
 {'mountpoint': '/mnt/data', 'name': 'DATA', 'size': '5,5T'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sdd', 'size': '3,7T'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sdd1', 'size': '3,7T'},
 {'mountpoint': '/mnt/data2', 'name': 'DATA2', 'size': '3,7T'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sde', 'size': '9,1T'},
 {'mountpoint': None, 'name': 'sde1', 'size': '9,1T'}]
```

Comment: how do I manage to print out the newly made list so I can check it in the terminal?